# How to test that a method should take more than X seconds to finish(with JUnit)?

Tags: junit, infinite-loop

Basically I need the opposite behaviour of the `@Test(timeout=X)` annotation.

The problem I want to solve is to detect in some way that the method never ends (as a right behaviour). I am assuming that if the method didn't stop after X seconds, I am sure "it will never end".

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```
@Test
public void methodDoesNotReturnFor5Seconds() throws Exception {
  Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      methodUnderTest();
    }
  });
  t.start();
  t.join(5000);
  assertTrue(t.isAlive());
  // possibly do something to shut down methodUnderTest
}
```