# java.util.concurrent: Transition from Runnable to Executor interface

Tags: java, concurrency, runnable, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I am writing a JUnit test case for a DSL, and I need to ensure that the method under test does never end (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1393080/238421)).

The [provided solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1393099/238421) is fine, but I would like to use the "new" [Executor interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) (Java 5.0 onwards):

```
@Test
public void methodDoesNotReturnFor5Seconds() throws Exception {
  Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      methodUnderTest();
    }
  });
  t.start();
  t.join(5000);
  assertTrue(t.isAlive());
  // possibly do something to shut down methodUnderTest
}
```

How can I translate the above code from the "old" `Thread`/`Runnable` interface to the "new" `ExecutorService`/`Executor` interface?

Comment: Check out `awaitTermination` of `ExecutorService`.

Comment: use Callable and block the method call using Future. For creating threads u can use ExecutorService

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind providing an example? I have trouble understanding `Future` and `ExecutorService` -- I tried a couple of examples, but I ended up with quite complicated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Future<?> future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        methodUnderTest();
    } 
});
try {
    future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    fail("The task has completed before 5 seconds");
}
catch (TimeoutException e) {
    // expected
}
```